# Is it feasible to run Kotlin-Scripts inside an Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's say I am writing an Android App and I want to implement parts of the logic in Kotlin-Script.

I managed to execute those scripts by using `org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory` in the App's `META-INFO.services`' `javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` setting.

So that works technically.

However, would it be really feasible to do this in a production app on Android, bringing the whole Kotlin compiler?

Comment: AFAIK, that dependency actually links in the Kotlin compiler -- it's not calling out to a command-line compiler or something. So, if you have it running, you have already demonstrated its feasibility. Your problems will be size, speed, and the restrictions placed by various app distribution channels.